# Unable to pass AWS WAF validation with React Dropzone

Tags: react-hooks, react-dropzone, amazon-waf

I am working on a task where an image would need to be stored on database, but AWS WAF is not allowing me to send the image.

I tried to remove the possible metadata in the image using EXIF, but it did not work because the function remove MetaData does not exist in the library which was describing in one of possible solutions I found.

The image does not seem to have any metadata, but WAF is still complaining.

How or what to do to bypass or to fix this issue? Is there a way to regenerate the image file into another new image file before sending it to the database?